# connected components and relationships in Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a graph with 3 million nodes with many (and little) connected components.
I need to find:
  - Number of connected components
  - List of relationships for each component (so I can extract the property)

I have spent two days with Neo4J+Java, perhaps it is impossible? :-(

PS I also tried with https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_cc but it's toooooo slow and doesn't work with Neo4J 2.0.0M6

thanks to anyone that have a opinion!
Lucio

PPS
In the image that I have attached, there are 3 connected components!
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10400004/Cattura.PNG

With a DFS i get error " GC overhead limit exceeded"

Comment: 3 million nodes shouldn't be a big deal at all. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling.